# How to download a static file (like .docx) from server, using react.js as front-end and express.js as back-end?

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs

I'm trying this, first, on my localhost. The express.js server is running on port 5000 
and the client is running on port 3000. What is the best approach for handling this and what should I write on the react client side? I tried with some examples around but didn't work. Thanks in advance for your answer.

The file I wanna download is in the same directory as server.js

**server.js** //expres.js

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('download', (req, res) => {
    console.log("descarga")
    const docPath = path.join(__dirname, 'example.docx');

    res.download(docPath, 'example.docx', function(err){
      if (err) {
        // if the file download fails, we throw an error
        throw err;
      }
      console.log('Someone just downloaded our file!');
    });
  })

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('Server Started...'));
```

### **downloadFile.js** //react

```
const downloadFile = () => {

    const onSubmitDownload = () => {
        ........
    }

    return (
         <form onSubmit = {onSubmitDownload} >
           <input type="submit" value="Download" className="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4"/>
         </form>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are going for a static file serve concept, no need to go width get request.

Simply use 
Url= `localhost:5000/download/example.docx`;

```
    app.use('/download', express.static(__dirname'));
```

if you want to request the file without file name u can write the callback function inside the express static

In React Application

Using link click

```
downloadEmployeeData = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/download/example.docx')
            .then(response => {
                response.blob().then(blob => {
                    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    let a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = 'employees.json';
                    a.click();
                });
                //window.location.href = response.url;
        });
    }
```

or automatic download

```
window.open('http://localhost:5000/download/example.docx', '_blank');
```